# ksh - global function

Tags: function, global, ksh

In ksh, I need to declare un global function, but I don't find the correct code.
Could you tell if is it possible and how ?

Exemple of my code :

```
$ cat script1.ksh
#/bin/ksh
.  ./lib.ksh
printVar "script1"
./script2.ksh

$ cat script2.ksh
#/bin/ksh
printVar "script2"

$ cat lib.ksh
function printVar {
    echo "$1"
}
```

Execution :

```
$ ./script1.ksh
script1
./script2.ksh: line 2: printVar: command not found
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You need to put `.  ./lib.ksh` in `script2.ksh` the same way as you put it in `script1.ksh`

Comment: Consider putting the function definition in a file `printVar` and adding the directory where you store the function definition to the environment variable `FPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `script2.ksh` so it is aware of your "function library" in `lib.ksh` like this:

```
#/bin/ksh
.  ./lib.ksh         # Dot in my function library
printVar "script2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Include lib.ksh in script2 as Setchell said, or include script2 in script1:

```
$ cat script1.ksh
#/bin/ksh
. ./lib.ksh
printVar "script1"
. ./script2.ksh

$ cat script2.ksh
#/bin/ksh
printVar "script2"

$ cat lib.ksh
function printVar {
    echo "$1"
}
```